# updating jsonb object using raw query

Tags: node.js, postgresql

i have this field in profile model

```
loginPrize: {
            type: DataTypes.JSONB,
            defaultValue : {
                day : 0,
                lastClaimed : dayjs().subtract(1,'d').format(),
                collected : false
            }
        },
```

and i want to update it using raw query

```
let loginPrize = {
                day: prizes.day,
                lastClaimed: dayjs().format(),
                collected: true
            }
let stringPrize = JSON.stringify(loginPrize)
await Profile.sequelize?.query(
`update profile set ${prizes.type} = ${prizes.type} + ${prizes.prize} , 
 loginPrize = to_jsonb(${stringPrize}::jsonb) ,where "playerId" = ${id}
 `)
```

and i am getting error ***"syntax error at or near "{""***

how to update it

Comment: Post the actual query beeing performed, that causes this error.

Comment: @madflow i posted the query with the error i am getting .. i want to update this loginPrize in profile model using raw sql .. as u can see the 2nd code i converted the loginprize i wanna store it to string and used it in the update query and i got the error mentioned up

Comment: You need to post the query, that is actually send to the database - not the query you prepared on the code level.

Comment: @madflow ok here it is ...      "update profile set energy = energy + 100 , loginPrize = to_jsonb({\"day\":1,\"lastClaimed\":\"2023-01-05T13:50:49+02:00\",\"collected\":true}::jsonb) ,where \"playerId\" = 77"

Comment: The loginPrice is already a JSON string, so you do not need "to_jsonb". Also: Use Replacements: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/#replacements - so sequelize can quote it properly.

Comment: @madflow thank you it worked by using replacement

Comment: @madflow Please make that an answer

Answer (score 0):

1. The loginPrice is already a JSON string, so you do not need "to_jsonb".
2. Use Replacements: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/#replacements  - so sequelize can quote it properly